# Foundation Block Grid and nth-child selector

Tags: css, wordpress, css-selectors, zurb-foundation

I'm right now working on a WordPress Theme with FoundationPress. I used the Sass Block Grid to display posts of a Custom Post Type, two in one row.

Now I'd like to give the even ones different styles (margin-top). Tried to do it with the nth-child selector, but it doesn't seem to work. All of the columns are displayed as odd or in a 1,3,5 and so on cycle.

Is this a common problem? Or is the block grid just not made to work with selectors like this?

Thanks in advance :)
Sabine

Comment: Can you please show what type of selector do you use? Look at this example: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_nth-child_odd_even

Comment: @NadezhdaSerafimova

I'm using the Foundation Block Grid, and the :nth-child selector. When putting in (odd) all of the columns get that styling, with (even) none of them get the styling. The code is down below in a new answer, because of the formating.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I have found the solution: I used :nth-of-type(2n) instead of :nth-child(2) and it worked and then it clicked :D I've mistaken the child thing with using it on li, when i should have used it on ul.

Oh man, worked way too much today. My bad...

Anyway, thanks so much for your time :)

The HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#linktopost">
      <span class="imgborder"><img src="#linktoimage" alt=""></span>
      <span class="projectinfo">
        <p class="skills">Skillset 1</p>
        <h3>Project 1</h3></span>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#linktopost">
      <span class="imgborder"><img src="#linktoimage" alt=""></span>
      <span class="projectinfo">
        <p class="skills">Skillset 2</p>
        <h3>Project 2</h3></span>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#linktopost">
      <span class="imgborder"><img src="#linktoimage" alt=""></span>
      <span class="projectinfo">
        <p class="skills">Skillset 3</p>
        <h3>Project 3</h3></span>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#linktopost">
      <span class="imgborder"><img src="#linktoimage" alt=""></span>
      <span class="projectinfo">
        <p class="skills">Skillset 4</p>
        <h3>Project 4</h3></span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The CSS:

```
ul{
    margin-top: 50px;
  }

  ul li{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 60px;
  }

  ul li:nth-of-type(2n){
    margin-top: 100px;
  }
```